# Firefox: no CSS errors/warnings in the log

Tags: html, css

I created a site with a bogus CSS code:

```
a { 
    foobar: 8888;
}
```

Then opened the page in Firefox. I looked in the web console and I can see no errors/warnings. Why?

My html head is:

```
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
    <script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: I didn't axpect to see such a question from a user with High reputation, have you ever seen css errors on the browser console???

Comment: @TheFlash High reps. can come from another language, making something simple to you difficult for someone else

Comment: CSS warnings used to appear in the Firefox web console: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=798592 . I thought they could be included so as to warn the developer (maybe they made a typo).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no warning in web console because wrong CSS rules simply has no effect in the page.

Comment: I add: it's impossible for any browser to check if a rule it's wrong (foobar), not included in the page (#myDivNotInPage) or browser-only support rule, so basically it's just ignored

Comment: You are right, css rules can be edited in real time on browsers even to check if are wrong or not